# Mongo find and project nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I store documents like that:

```
const offer = {
  _id: UUID("b0b7bb8b-374b-4957-9902-536939f510e0"),
  name: "test name",
  products: [
    { id: "1", name: "Product name 1" }, 
    { id: "2", name: "Product name 2" }] }
  ]
};
```

I need query to get only id of offer and id of product for given product id:

```
{  _id: UUID("b0b7bb8b-374b-4957-9902-536939f510e0"), id: "1" }
```

To achieve that I try with query:

```
db.offers.find({ "products.id": "1" }, { _id: 1, "products.id": 1 })
```

But result was:

```
{ 
    _id: UUID("b0b7bb8b-374b-4957-9902-536939f510e0"),
    products: [
        { id: "1", name: "Product name 1" }, 
        { id: "2", name: "Product name 2" }
    ] 
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please check below query help you:

```
db.getCollection('offer').find({ "products.id": "1" },{"products.$":1})
```

> Also Please correct your JSON at `{ id: "2", name: "Product name 2" }] }`